# Android drag and drop

Tags: android

Here i created a dragable imageview .This is my sample code(not given full code)

```
public class mainClass extends Activity 
{     
    MyView obj1,obj2;   
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        AbsoluteLayout layout = new AbsoluteLayout(LearnKid.this);

        layout.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(
                                   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0,0));
        obj1 = new MyView(this);
        obj2 = new MyView(this);

        layout.addView(obj1);
        layout.addView(obj2);

        setContentView(layout);

    }
}
class MyView extends ImageView 
{
    public MyView(Context context)
     {

           super(context);
    }
     public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
     {
        center_X= (int)event.getRawX();
        center_Y = (int)event.getRawY();
        this.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,center_X-10,center_Y-(70)));
    }
}
```

Here i get 2 separate imageviews and also it is dragable.
But how do i check whether the first image has crossed the second image.
Because at that point i want to stop the dragable option.

Plz help

thanx in advance....

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to provide the initial logic for this. You have to get the position of the item you are checking against and compare whether your dragged items x or y coordinate (or both depends on what you want to achieve) have passed the your second items x and/or y coordinate. You need a basic understanding of the Cartesian coordinate system.

This you can implement in the dragging logic or when you release the object (take the finger from it).

Now just to clear something else up. Is there any special reason you're using an AbsoluteLayout? If not then please don't use it as it is deprecated and it's usage isn't encouraged.

Comment: ya..i tried the above logic also.It will check only when the second view passes the exact coordinate. This will not give the full effect of drag and drop.so i didnt use...................

As the case of Absolute Layout, i want to position the view in a particular position during startup
Is their another way..???

Thanx for your sugestion...

Comment: @Antony I'm sorry but I fail to understand why it would not work. It seems like the logic you've tried is just not correct.

Answer (score 0):

AABB axis aligned bounding boxes

each time you want to update the position and the box being dragged you test if they overlap

you can try and adapt this

```
axmin = gofd.getPosition().x-gofd.getObjectSize().x/2f;
    axmax = gofd.getPosition().x+gofd.getObjectSize().x/2f;
    aymin = gofd.getPosition().y-gofd.getObjectSize().y/2f;
    aymax = gofd.getPosition().y+gofd.getObjectSize().y/2f;
    Enumeration<Integer> e2 = myHash.getKeys();
    while( e2. hasMoreElements() ){
        GameObject toDraw = myHash.getGameObjectForID(e2.nextElement());
        if(toDraw != null){
            bymax = toDraw.getPosition().y+toDraw.getObjectSize().y/2f;
                bymin = toDraw.getPosition().y-toDraw.getObjectSize().y/2f;
                bxmin = toDraw.getPosition().x-toDraw.getObjectSize().x/2f;
                bxmax = toDraw.getPosition().x+toDraw.getObjectSize().x/2f;
                if(!(axmax<bxmin || bxmax <axmin || aymax<bymin || bymax <aymin)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

gofd = game object finger drag

this is a code snippet from an old version of my game

the myHash contains a reference to the images datastrucutre I was using, but it shouldn't far off what you need

Comment: LOL I gave you the code for the widest situation ^^ I test the object being dragged against all the others. if your working with 2D boxes you can't make it simpler. line 1-4 you calculate the sides of the dragged box line 5-8 loop on all the other objects line 9-12 calculate the sides of the other object line 13 test